# Proper way of fading in/out an image when hovering an element

Tags: javascript, css

I'm doing some tests with the animeJS animation library (www.animejs.com) and I'd like to use it for changing an image for another when the user moves the mouse over some div elements in the page. Also, I'd like to swap the images with a nice fade-out/fade-in effect. You can see an example in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n5c5rgjo/3/

If you try it, you'll see that it works fine until you move the mouse from one div to the other while the animation is being played. To avoid a flickering effect in this case, I added a 'lock' (`animLock` variable in the code) to allow only one animation at a time. This creates another problem, because the image is not updated properly.

Could someone show me a better way of dealing with this problem?  Thanks!

Comment: To whoever downvoted: if you don't mind, could you explain why? I'm just asking something I don't know, and before I posted this question I looked at the animeJS examples and googled for some info on what I wanted but I couldn't find anything useful. Also, this subject is new for me so I consider quite normal to ask questions that might be silly for a lot of more experienced developers. But, in my opinion, if you think that a question deserves a downvote, of course you can give it, but at least you could say why or give some advice to help the newbie. Sometimes learning is so frustrating!!

Answer (score 0):

Ad this CSS

```
img{
  transition: all 0.8s;
}
img:hover{
  opacity:0.1;
 transition: all 0.8s;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I want to change the image when I hover on other divs, not on the image itself, so this changes won't apply to my case, sorry.